# How to insert backend validation error message into angular-schema-form?

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-scope, angular-schema-form

I am evaluating angular, reading [documentation](https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/blob/development/docs/index.md#inject-errors-into-form-aka-backend-validation)  and trying to understand where to insert error messages, which come from backend (in the example below - userNameAlreadyTaken on the name field), example from documentation with my attempt to guess where to put things:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
angular.module('myModule', ['schemaForm']);
angular.module('myModule', ['schemaForm'])
       .controller('FormController', function($scope) {
  $scope.schema = {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
      name: { type: "string", minLength: 2, 
              title: "Name", description: "Name or alias"
      },
      title: {
        type: "string",
        enum: ['dr','jr','sir','mrs','mr','NaN','dj']
      }
    }
  };

  $scope.form = [
   {
    "key": "name",
    "validationMessages": {
         "userNameAlreadyTaken"
    }
   },
   {          type: "submit", style: 'btn-success', title: "Save"}
  ];
  $scope.model = {};
  $scope.$broadcast('schemaForm.error.name','tv4-302',false);
});
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myModule']);
});
</script>

<div ng-controller="FormController">
   <form sf-schema="schema" sf-form="form" sf-model="model" action="action_url" ></form>
</div>
```

And the above code renders the form, but without error message. I expect that once the page is loaded, the "name" field is "red", because it is supposed contain an error. Documention of angular-schema-form assumes one has intuition on how angular works, so the code snippets are without relation to their location in the code. And there are typos, like scope without dollar and

```
"validationMessages": { "userNameAlreadyTaken" }
```

I am not sure, should there be a list or what? List doesn't work. Event broadcast also does not work. Tried both custom and tv-4, per documentation.

I am not even sure I am calling the broadcast from the right place. And how to get access to the right $scope if I need to call it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Angular schema form documentation does contain errors.

Here is a working example:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    angular.module('myModule', ['schemaForm']);
    angular.module('myModule', ['schemaForm'])
      .controller('FormController', function($scope) {
        $scope.schema = {
          type: "object",
          properties: {
            name: {
              type: "string",
              minLength: 2,
              title: "Name",
              description: "Name or alias"
            },
            title: {
              type: "string",
              enum: ['dr', 'jr', 'sir', 'mrs', 'mr', 'NaN', 'dj']
            }
          }
        };
        $scope.form = [{
          key: "name",
          validationMessage: {
            userNameAlreadyTaken: "Username already taken!"
          }
        }, {
          type: "submit",
          style: 'btn-success',
          title: "Save"
        }];

        $scope.model = {};

        $scope.onSubmit = function(form) {
          $scope.$broadcast('schemaForm.error.name', 'userNameAlreadyTaken', false);
        };

      });
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myModule']);
  });
</script>

<div ng-controller="FormController">
  <form sf-schema="schema" sf-form="form" sf-model="model" action="action_url" name="myForm" ng-submit="onSubmit(myForm)"></form>
</div>
```

Main problem was:

```
"validationMessages": {
    "userNameAlreadyTaken"
}
```

This, of course, is not valid JavaScript and it should look like this (key value pair):

```
validationMessage: {
    userNameAlreadyTaken: "Username already taken!"
}
```

And in your controller you can do this:

```
if (valid) {
    $scope.$broadcast('schemaForm.error.name', 'userNameAlreadyTaken', true);
} else {
    $scope.$broadcast('schemaForm.error.name', 'userNameAlreadyTaken', false);
}
```

Before this you just need to write code that comunicates with the backend and handle the response.

Also, if you need to, you can add multiple messages:

```
validationMessage: {
   "userNameAlreadyTaken": "Username already taken!",
   "someOtherMessage": "Some other validation message."
}
...
$scope.$broadcast('schemaForm.error.name', "userNameAlreadyTaken", false);
$scope.$broadcast('schemaForm.error.name', "someOtherMessage", false);
```

Comment: Thanks for syntax corrections, however, even after these changes the error message is not shown when page loads. Is there anything else I need to add to the page? For example, it is not clear where the "schemaForm" comes from, or is it something known to angular?

Comment: "Before this you just need to write code that communicates with the backend and handle the response." I am not using AJAX or whatever, but page reloads and normal form submits. (that is maybe misuse of Angular)

Comment: Oh, you are right! Actually, I have encountered the same problem you are having. I have updated the example code by adding onSubmit event (and the directive on form tag). Now it shows the error on Save.